# How do I check "children" and not render the parent?

Tags: reactjs

Can "SidebarMenu" return null if "children" are not rendered?

**Symptom**: render div with "border: red;"
**Fix**: div with "border: red;" not render

[CodeSandbox for experiments](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-fog-k8fol?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Work!</h1>

      <SidebarMenu>
        <AccessControl enabled={false}>
          <Item number="1" />
          <Item number="2" />
          <Item number="3" />
        </AccessControl>
      </SidebarMenu>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function AccessControl({ enabled, children }) {
  if (enabled) {
    return children;
  }

  return null;
}

function Item({ number }) {
  return <p>Hello {number}</p>;
}

function SidebarMenu({ children }) {
  // check "children" here and return null

  return <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>{children}</div>;
}
```

**UPDATE**: You can't make checks for "props: enabled".  I added this conditionally to show that children or null can be returned

Comment: You mean if there are no children, or if there is a problem / error with rendering the children?

Comment: if no children.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if children of `<AccessControl>` is defined, if not return null.

```
function SidebarMenu({ children }) {
    if (!children.props.children) return null;
    return <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>{children}</div>;
}
```

Here is an example that shows when the check will work and the side bar will not be rendered:

```
import React from "react";

const items = null;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Work!</h1>

      <SidebarMenu>
        <AccessControl enabled={true}>
          {(items || []).map(x => <Item key={x} number={`${x}`} />)}
        </AccessControl>
      </SidebarMenu>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function AccessControl({ enabled, children }) {
  if (enabled) {
    return children;
  }

  return null;
}

function Item({ number }) {
  return <p>Hello {number}</p>;
}

function SidebarMenu({ children }) {
  if (!children.props.children) return null;

  return <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't work. You can check in CodeSandbox. Because children exists as an object

Comment: @italant Ah, sorry.  Missed that the immediate child is an `<AccessControl>`.  I updated my answer.  However, in your example there will always be children under `<AccessControl>` unless you change the items to be rendered dynamically, so that check will always return false and children will always be rendered.

Comment: "children.props.children" contains 3 children. It's probably easier for me to rewrite the code than to make up crutches. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, thus my comment that that check will NEVER hit given your example and the need for dynamic items.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this :

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-night-6hbqw?file=/src/App.js

```
function SidebarMenu({ children }) {
  // check "children" here and return null
  if (!children.props.enabled) return null;

  return <div style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't work.  Because children exists

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tell you right away. You can't check for "props: enabled". Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <SidebarMenu>
   {enabled &&
     <AccessControl>
      <Item number="1" />
      <Item number="2" />
      <Item number="3" />
     </AccessControl>
   }
</SidebarMenu>
```

if u want to render AccesControl when enabled is **true** this is how you do it

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tell you right away. You can't check for "props: enabled". Thanks for answering :)